# I can't run the gcc compiler in VScode even though I have everything set up

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio-code, g++

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to set up C and C++,
I have the C/C++ extension pack installed and enabled on VScode,
I have mysys64 installed on the C:\ drive,
I added the Mingw-w64 destination folder path, with \mingw64\bin appended, to the system path in Edit environment variables for your account (windows settings).

The problem is that I can't run the g++ compiler (checking the version also doesn't run) and I'm very sure the address at system path is correct because I've checked it more than 6 times and I've also followed every single step on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp until Check your MinGW installation (because it doesn't work).

The error messages I get are:
Command 'g++' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install g++,
and when I try: "Build Hello World" on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
I get:
[/image/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4zzK.png)
Notes:

- I run Windows 10 Pro, version: 21H2, OS build: 19044.1826
- I already had WSL(ubuntu) installed before mysys64

Edit: I used a different machine and followed the same steps, it works there now. Looks like the problem is with the machine

Comment: what did you see if you type 'path' on your command prompt?

Comment: PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP\;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1\bin;;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;

Comment: try to follow this [instruction](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-run-a-c-program-in-visual-studio-code) to set it up again.

Answer (score 1):

Install WSL extension in VSCode, run VSCode from WSL (WSL2 better because its faster), then install g++ (sudo apt install g++) from WSL; MingW is evil :)

Comment: WSL 2 does not work with serial ports...

Comment: @LucVandenbroucke maybe could try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) for USB; M$ won't let you lie ... is Ellipsis